# input from console application to another c# console application?

Tags: c#, redirect, processstartinfo, redirectstandardoutput

I want to develop a c# application `(a.exe)` that input to another c# application `(b.exe)`
`b.exe` does not take any arguments.

`b.exe -call or b.exe call` and so on does not work

When I open `b.exe` from cmd it take arguments like this:

```
b:call
b:command 2

....

b:command n
```

How can I feed `b.exe` from `a.exe`?

I have used but it does not work.

```
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("b.exe")
        {
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };

        var p = new Process { StartInfo = psi };

        p.Start();
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("call");
```

Comment: Do you need application or basic shell redirect would do? I.e. `a.exe | b.exe`?

Comment: i want to implement an application can call commands of b.exe

Comment: b:call
b:help
b:com1

Comment: What about IPC? As wcf

Comment: Why does `b.exe -call` or `b.exe call` not work? If you are creating b.exe, then you have control and could definitely make it work using command line arguments, standard input, or both. Also, please elaborate on the error messages or anything else that might be useful to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I understand from your question:

- `a.exe` starts `b.exe`
- `a.exe` uses either command line arguments or standard input to pass commands/requests to `b.exe`
- `b.exe` received the commands/requests and passes information through StandardOutput

Using command line arguments is a bit simpler, except you will need to run `b.exe` multiple times for each request/command.

```
// b.exe
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // using command line arguments
    foreach (var arg in args)
        ProcessArg(arg);

    // if using input, then use something like if processing line by line
    // string line = Console.ReadLine();
    // while (line != "exit" || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    //     ProcessArg(line);

    // or you can read the input stream
    var reader = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput());
    var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // TODO: parse the text and find the commands
}

static void ProcessArg(string arg)
{
    if (arg == "help") Console.WriteLine("b.exe help output");
    if (arg == "call") Console.WriteLine("b.exe call output");
    if (arg == "command") Console.WriteLine("b.exe command output");
}

// a.exe
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Testing -- Send help, call, command  --> to b.exe
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("b.exe", "help call command")
    {
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
    };
    var p = new Process() { StartInfo = psi };
    p.ErrorDataReceived += p_ErrorDataReceived;
    p.OutputDataReceived += p_OutputDataReceived;
    p.Start();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();

    // if sending data through standard input (May need to use Write instead
    // of WriteLine. May also need to send end of stream (0x04 or ^D / Ctrl-D)
    StreamWriter writer = p.StandardInput;
    writer.WriteLine("help");
    writer.WriteLine("call");
    writer.WriteLine("exit");
    writer.Close();

    p.WaitForExit();
}

static void p_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("a.exe error: " + e.Data ?? "(null)");
}

static void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("a.exe received: " + e.Data ?? "(null)");
}
```

Look at the [OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ErrorDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) events as well as the MSDN sample in those methods.

One consideration is that you cannot pipe output from a program running with Administrative privileges. You would need to save the output and then pass the output to the other program.

I found a helpful [CSharpTest](http://csharptest.net/projects/library/) library with a [ProcessRunner](https://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/source/browse/src/Library/Processes/ProcessRunner.cs) class a while back. Browse the "InternalStart" method of ProcessRunner for an example.

Comment: If `a.exe` needs to read output from `b.exe` then you need the OutputDataReceived event. It is confusing because it would seem it is input, but it is the output from the `b.exe` process.

Comment: i donot have access to source of b.exe,
i want to run a command like b:call from a.exe,
i have enabled RedirectiStandardInput but there is no response from b.exe

Comment: What is the separator between the commands? NewLine, space, or something else? I just made `a.exe` and `b.exe` and it worked. Have you tested `b.exe` from the command line? Can you type in commands? Does it respond? Do you have an `exit` command or does it look for the end of stream? These are questions you will need to find an answer for.